# Consulta Mysql desde Javascript con Ajax

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

Quería saber cómo puedo hacer una consulta Mysql **a una hora concreta** con este reloj que tengo en Javascript. Tengo entendido que hay que usar Ajax, pero he intentado incluir la parte de Ajax dentro del if de la hora que deseo, y todo deja de funcionar (el reloj y la consulta). ¿Alguna ayuda?

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
       <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script>

    function clock(id){ //El parametro id es donde se escribirá la hora

    var seeTime = "2017-10-02 13:42:20"; //fecha y hora de gatillamiento de evento
    var clock = document.getElementById(id); //Asignamos una variable al elemento del documento donde escribiremos la hora

    var Digital=new Date(); //Creamos el objeto Date para obtener la fecha completa
    var h = Digital.getHours(); //hora
    var m = Digital.getMinutes(); //mins
    var s = Digital.getSeconds(); //segs
    var year = Digital.getFullYear(); //año
    var month = Digital.getMonth()+1; //mes, +1 ya que este metodo da de 0-11 en vez de 1-12
    var day = Digital.getDate(); //dia


    //Agregamos los 0 si son menores a 10
    if(month < 10){ month = "0"+month; }
    if(day < 10){ day = "0"+day; }
    if(h < 10){ h = "0"+h; }
    if(m < 10){ m = "0"+m; }
    if(s < 10){ s = "0"+s; }

    var myTime = year+"-"+month+"-"+day+" "+h+":"+m+":"+s; //Esta variable es para obtener la fecha completa en formato "YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss" PARA GATILLAR EVENTO

    h = parseInt(h); //Volvemos a hacer numerico la hora, ya que concatenmos arriba
    var hs = "PM"; //Damos la premisa que es PM. "hs" de hour system
    if(h > 12){ //Si la hora es mayor que 12.... 
    h -= 12; //Quitamos 12 horas de modo que las 16hr es 16-12=4
    }
    else{ //De no ser así dejamos tal cual y decimos que es AM
    hs = "AM";
    }

    var showTime = h+":"+m+":"+s+" "+hs; //Obtenemos la hora a mostrar "HH:mm:ss AM/PM"
    clock.innerHTML = showTime; //Escribimos hora

        if(myUnixTime(myTime) == myUnixTime(seeTime)){ //Si myTime == seeTime gatillamos evento 
        //Gatillamos evento

         $(function() { //usamos function porque document.ready es deprecated desde jQuery 3

        //Guardamos una variable timer para poder pararla si ocurre error
        var timer = setInterval(update, 1000);

        function update() 
        { 
            //Almacenamos la petición ajax en la variable request
            var request = $.ajax
                ({
                    url: "copia de consulta.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    dataType: "json"
                });


                //Usamos request y evaluamos usando done y fail, es lo recomendado por jQuery
                //done se lanzará cuando la petición Ajax tenga éxito
                request.done(function( datos ) 
                {
                    console.log(datos);

                    // Creamos una variable y evaluamos datos
                    var txtHTML;
                    if (!datos.error)
                    {
                       //Si se espera más de una fila hay que leer datos en un bucle
                        /*txtHTML=datos.ID+"<br />"+datos.nombre;*/

                        $.each(datos, function(key, value) 
                            { 
                                txtHTML +=key + ": " + value; 
                            });

                     }else{
                        txtHTML=datos.error;
                        clearInterval(timer); //paramos el timer
                     }
                     $('#contenedor').text(txtHTML);
                });

                //fail se lanzará cuando la petición Ajax falle      
                request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) 
                {
                    alert( "Falló la petición Ajax: " + textStatus );
                    //Paramos el timer
                    clearInterval(timer); 
                });

            }

    });

        //document.getElementById('liveclock').innerHTML = "Hello World!";

        }
    }


    function myUnixTime(d){ //Esta funcion obtiene los segundos de una fecha dada en formato "YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss" en este caso la fecha es el parametro "d"
    var mArr = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]; //Cantidad dias de c/mes

    var spl = d.split(" "); //Separamos la fecha de la hora spl[0] = fecha, spl[1] = hora
    var date = spl[0].split("-"); //Separamos los datos de la fecha date[0] = año, date[1] = mes, date[2] = dia

    // Es necesario usar parseInt() para obtener el valor numerico de los datos
    var y = parseInt(date[0])*365*24*60*60; //Agregamos los segundos que tiene un año
    var m = parseInt(date[1]); //Obtenemos el mes, lo usaremos luego
    var d = parseInt(date[2])*24*60*60; //Obtenemos los segundos de un dia

    //Aqui lo que haremos es sumar la cantidad de dias de los meses que han pasado 
    var mAdd = 0; //Los dias se agregaran en esta variable
    for(var k=0;k<m;k++){ //Partimos desde el indice 0 de mArr (cantidad dias/mes) hasta el mes en el que estamos
    mAdd += mArr[k]; //Agregamos a mAdd la cantidad de dias de dias del mes con indice k
    }

    m = mAdd*24*60*60; //Obtenemos la cantidad de segundos del total de meses transcurridos

    var time = spl[1].split(":"); //Separamos los datos de la hora time[0] = hora, time[1] = mins, time[2] = seg

    var h = parseInt(time[0])*60*60; //Agregamos segundos en 1 hora
    var m = parseInt(time[1])*60; //Agregamos segundos en 1 min
    var s = parseInt(time[2]); //...

    return y+m+d+h+m+s; //retornamos la suma de todos los segundos obtenidos
    }


    window.onload=function(){ //Cuando la ventana cargue...
    setInterval("clock('liveclock')",1000); //Creamos un intervalo de 1000ms a la funcion myClock, ms= mili segundos, 1000ms = 1s
    };

    </script>
    <div class="reloj">
              <br><span class="clock" id="liveclock"></span><br></div>
         <script type="text/javascript">

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

     <section class="content">
      <p>CONSULTA BASE DE DATOS CADA SEGUNDO</p>
      <p><div id="contenedor">0</div>
     </section>

    </body>
    </html>
```

El archivo "copia de consulta.php":

```
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "contraseña", "nombre bd");
    // verificar la conexión 

    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        $arrRespuesta=array("error"=>"Conexión fallida: ".$mysqli->connect_error);

    }else{

         $consulta = "SELECT * FROM productos";

         if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)) {
            // obtener un array asociativo 
            $arrRespuesta=array();

            while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                $arrRespuesta[]=$fila;
            } 

            // liberar el conjunto de resultados 
            $resultado->free();
         }else{
            $arrRespuesta=array("error"=>"Hubo un problema con la consulta");

         }
        // cerrar la conexión 
        $mysqli->close();
    }


    //Al final de todo imprimimos el JSON que será recogido en la petición //Ajax/jQuery
    $json = json_encode($arrRespuesta);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $json;
```

Comment: Si copias y pegas desde `function update() {`sin incluír `document.ready` adentro de tu if, funciona?

Comment: javascript se ejecuta desde el cliente (al menos que uses node), creo que estas confundido necesitas un lenguaje de programacion como PHP .NET java......, entre otros que haga eso por ti

Comment: ¿Podrías identificar **qué** es lo que no funciona? Si la función que hace la consulta es esta `update()`, sólo tienes que llamarla donde la necesites. Es necesario depurar el código, poner mensajes con `alert` o con `console.log`  en cada etapa para ver lo que está ocurriendo. Puede que lo que no funcione sea el código PHP, eso es fácil de depurar, antes de lanzar la consulta en sí, si tienes problemas, poniendo un simple `echo "Hola";` en el PHP. O sea, no asumas que algo debe funcionar porque sí, sobre todo cuando intervienen varios factores: Ajax, PHP, JS, Base de datos, etc.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano, Lixus y JackNavaRow. Colocar la función update() en el lugar que deseo que se ejecute es lo primero que he hecho. Lo he dicho al formular la pregunta, repito ese trozo: "...pero he intentado incluir la parte de Ajax dentro del if de la hora que deseo, y todo deja de funcionar (el reloj y la consulta)...".

Comment: Pues yo no veo **dónde** haces la llamada a la función  `update()`. Si en la pregunta no pones el código como lo tienes, es imposible poder ayudarte. Y además, incluye las otras partes que intervienen, por ejemplo el archivo `consulta.php`. Te hice varias preguntas y no comentas nada sobre ello. ¿Estás depurando y evaluando tu código en cada etapa?

Comment: Perdón @A.cedano, no había puesto el resto del código porque pensé que lo útil solo era el javascript y el ajax. Ahora lo he puesto tal y como lo estoy ejecutando, con el Ajax en el lugar donde lo tenía al realizar la pregunta.

Comment: @Matrix, he reproducido tu problema. El error puede estarse debiendo a dos posibles causas, 1º: El JSON no se está creando bien debido a un problema de codificación; 2º: Al ser un arreglo asociativo, debemos leer la respuesta `datos` usando dos bucles. Ahora edito la respuesta. He probado el código y me funciona, aunque he tenido que quitar la condición inicial que tienes, porque en mi caso nunca se cumplía: `if(myUnixTime(myTime) == myUnixTime(seeTime)){ //Si myTime == seeTime gatillamos evento`

Comment: @A.Cedano Perfectísimo!!! Ahora está todo correcto!!! Un millón de gracias por todo el trabajo y el esfuerzo que mi pregunta le ha dado, ha sido de una enorme ayuda! Además, por supuesto usaré sus respuestas y explicaciones para aprender este nuevo lenguaje para mi! Saludos!

Comment: Me alegro. Por favor lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Al fin lo hemos logrado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a señalar algunas partes problemáticas de tu código, aportando una solución.

También usaremos código actualizado, según las recomendaciones de jQuery.

He comentado las partes del código donde he introducido cambios.

> **NOTA DE EDICIÓN**:
>
> - Estableceremos el charset de la conexión a UTF-8 para asegurar que nuestro JSON se creará sin errores.
> - Leeremos la respuesta de Ajax dentro de dos bucles, puesto que estamos recibiendo un array asociativo.
> - La `var txtHTML="";` debe estar inicializada a `""` para que no te de `undefined` al principio.

### jQuery

```
$(function() { //usamos function porque document.ready es deprecated desde jQuery 3

    //Guardamos una variable timer para poder pararla si ocurre error
    var timer = setInterval(update, 1000);

    function update() 
    { 
        //Almacenamos la petición ajax en la variable request
        var request = $.ajax
            ({
                url: "copia de consulta.php", //¿Ese archivo se llama así realmente?
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "json"
            });

            
            //Usamos request y evaluamos usando done y fail, es lo recomendado por jQuery
            //done se lanzará cuando la petición Ajax tenga éxito
            request.done(function( datos ) 
            {

                // Creamos una variable y evaluamos datos
                var txtHTML="";
                if (!datos.error)
                {
                    //Si se espera más de una fila hay que leer datos en un bucle
                    //txtHTML=datos.ID+"<br />"+datos.nombre ;

                    $.each(datos, function(i, object) {
                        $.each(object, function(property, value) {
                            txtHTML +=property + "=" + value+"<br />";
                            //Prueba
                            console.log(property + "=" + value+"<br />");
                        });
                        txtHTML +="<hr />";   
                    });

                 }else{

                    txtHTML=datos.error;
                    clearInterval(timer); //paramos el timer
                 }
                 $('#contenedor').text(txtHTML);
            });

            //fail se lanzará cuando la petición Ajax falle         
            request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) 
            {
                alert( "Falló la petición Ajax: " + textStatus );
                //Paramos el timer
                clearInterval(timer); 
            });
    
    }

});
```

---

### PHP

Dado que jQuery espera una respuesta JSON, lo cual es una muy buena idea, en el código PHP construiremos una respuesta de ese tipo.

**Es muy importante guardar una variable e imprimir lo que sea sólo al final**. Por eso, nuestra variable `$arrRespuesta` será nuestra única variable, que tomará valores según lo que ocurra. Y la imprimiremos al final.

> **NOTA DE EDICIÓN:** Aquí sólo hemos añadido esta línea: `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");`

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "usuario", "contraseña", "base de datos");
// verificar la conexión 

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    $arrRespuesta=array("error"=>"Conexión fallida: ".$mysqli->connect_error);

}else{
     /*Establecemos el charset a la conexión para evitar datos erróneos*/
     $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
     $consulta = "SELECT * FROM productos";

     if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)) {
        // obtener un array asociativo 
        $arrRespuesta=array();
        while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
            $arrRespuesta[]=$fila;
        }

        // liberar el conjunto de resultados 
        $resultado->free();

     }else{

        $arrRespuesta=array("error"=>"Hubo un problema con la consulta");

     }

    // cerrar la conexión 
    $mysqli->close();
}



//Al final de todo imprimimos el JSON que será recogido en la petición Ajax/jQuery
$json = json_encode($arrRespuesta);
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
echo $json;
```

Comment: Hola nuevamente @A.Cedano, ante todo muchísimas gracias por la respuesta tan completa y elaborada. Solo devuelve un error al ejecutar todo, el resto está perfecto. El error es: "undefined <br />undefined". ¿Alguna ayuda sobre eso? Muchas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @Matrix ¿puedes ver lo que imprime el `console.log(datos);`? Yo asumí los nombres de columnas que había en tu pregunta pero puede que sean otros.

Comment: Sí, los nombres de las columnas eran esos, estaban correctos, pero parece que da error, no sé por qué.
¿Cómo se hace para imprimir el valor de console.log(datos);? Aunque de todas formas, veo que en el código ya escribiste eso justo debajo de request.done(function( datos )  {. ¿Tengo que hacer algo para imprimir el valor de lo que comentas?

Comment: En el navegador tienes que activar en la ventana llamada `Desarrollo` (no recuerdo si se llama así en todos los navegadores), una opción llamada `Mostrar consola de Javascript`. Entonces corres la página y podrás ver por consola lo que ya puse en `console.log`, es una forma de depurar el código, para ver lo que trae la variable datos. Si la tabla `productos` tiene una columna llamada `ID` y otra llamada `nombre` deberían verse los datos. Es importante que digas si se podrían recibir varias filas en la respuesta, porque entonces hay que modificar la forma de leer los resultados.

Comment: Ah gracias. Si he depurado correctamente, lo que se muestra al ejecutarse y dar el error que he dicho anteriormente, es:   
Array [ Object, Object ], qué se va repitiendo sin parar cada segundo a partir de la hora que le defino en el código. 
Por otra parte, lo que hay en "ID" es: 1,2; y en "nombre" hay: primero, segundo, sí, creo que se podrán recibir varias filas en la respuesta.

Comment: Bien. Significa que hay que leer la respuesta recorriendo el array y no directamente. Lo hice pensando que recibirías una sola fila.

Comment: He añadido esto: `$arr = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($arr as $arraydos){
    echo $arraydos; 
}` justo al final del archivo php, para mostrar el contenido recorriendo el array, pero arroja error: Parseerror de Ajax. ¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo solucionarlo? He buscado, pero no encuentro cómo. Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: @Matrix Al marcarla como solucionado creí que lo tenías resuelto. Ahora edito el código mostrando cómo sería le lectura de un array.

Comment: @Matrix revisa el código editado. En el `done`  he puesto esto: `var obj = JSON.parse(datos);
                        $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
                             txtHTML +=key + ": " + value+"<br />";
                        });` de esa forma se concatena en `txtHTML` todo el contenido del array. Hay otras formas de recorrerlo y presentarlo, según tus necesidades.

Comment: Gracias. De momento no se muestra nada al añadir esa parte. ¿Tengo que sustituir algo o adaptarlo de alguna forma?

Comment: Esta línea `$('#contenedor').text(txtHTML);` indica que el resultado de la variable `txtHTML` se mostrará en el elemento del DOM (HTML) que tenga un `id="contenedor"`. No `name` u otra cosa. ¿Tienes algo parecido a esto en tu HTML: **`<div id="contenedor"></div>`**. Si lo tienes, debería mostrarse el texto ahí. Si no lo tienes, inclúyelo y prueba.

Comment: Ok. Lo he probado de esa manera, pero sigue sin visualizarse nada. Es un poco extraño. ¿Tengo que adaptar algo a los datos de mi base de datos en `var obj = JSON.parse(datos); $.each(obj, function(key, value) { txtHTML +=key + ": " + value+"<br />"; });`?

Comment: Sugiero que edites la pregunta, poniendo el código como lo tienes ahora, así podré revisarlo a ver dónde puede estar el fallo. Pon el  código HTML (sólo la parte relevante) el código Javascript/jQuery  y el código PHP.  ¿Tampoco muestra nada en la consola?

Comment: Gracias. Editado. En la consola muestra lo siguiente: Array [ Object, Object ] 
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: Ok @Matrix. Significa que no hace falta parsear el JSON. Entonces: **1.** Comenta esta línea : `//var obj = JSON.parse(datos);`  y **2.** Pon la variable `datos` en el bucle, en lugar de `obj`:  **`$.each(datos, function(key, value) {
                          txtHTML +=key + ": " + value+"<br />";
                    });`**

Comment: Gracias. @A.Cedano. Parece que sigue dando error. En la consola muestra: Array [ Object, Object ] y la web muestra: undefined 0: [object Object] 1: [object Object].

Comment: ¿Podrías editar la pregunta poniendo el código como lo tienes actualmente ? de ese modo se podrá hacer una revisión general.

Comment: No he modificado el código desde la última edición que hice hace unos días.

Comment: ¿No modificaste esta parte como te dije en un comentario anterior: `var obj = JSON.parse(datos); $.each(obj, function(key, value) { txtHTML +=key + ": " + value+"<br />"; });`? El parse no es necesario.

Comment: Sí, solo eso, y el resultado que arroja es lo que he comentado. Editado de nuevo.

Comment: Recuerden que está la opción de ir al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com) para hablar sobre cómo usar la respuesta, más detalles, etc. :)