# Pasar dato a ajax

Tags: jquery, json

Tengo un arreglo de cadenas JSON y deseo pasarlo a ajax, pero no sé como enviarlo y cómo recibirlo del lado del servidor, alguna idea?

```
$.ajax(
        {
            url: "WebS/webServices.aspx/funcion",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(parametro),
            destroy: true,
            success: function (result) {
                resultado = result.d;
            }
        }).done(function () {});
```

Donde parametro es el arreglo de cadenas JSON (he intentado con JSON.stringify y sin él) y he intentado recibirlo como:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string funcion(string parametro)
{
}
```

Pero recibo como error:

```
"El tipo System.String no se admite para la deserialización de una matriz."
```

Alguna idea de cómo puedo mandarlo??

Comment: Como comenta el error, podrías intentar recibir una matriz y no un string

Comment: Mmmm recibo la matriz de la siguiente forma : string[][] param y no me marca error, pero no sé como accesar a los valores que me regresa ya que intento hacer string v = param[0][0] y me dice que los limites en la matriz son incorrectos.

Comment: Prueba declarar un objeto en la función. Y luego ves como deserializarlo

Comment: ¿Cómo está constituido _exactamente_ `parametro`? Es un JSON, es una cadena, ¿qué es, cómo se forma esa variable?. Luego, tu código de petición Ajax es algo confuso, mezclas dos funciones que hacen lo mismo, me refiero a `success` y a `done`, siendo recomendada esta última. Aquí hay varios ejemplos de este tipo de peticiones, ¿has buscado? [Por ejemplo esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/104486/29967) de las que tengo a mano, más recientes.